# Matching a string value to a value in an imported excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, ip, subnet

I am trying to input an IP address that will match with an IP in my excel spreadhseet. It starts crashing in the  DataRow row = xlWorksheet.Rows[i]; line. I need it to loop because I am dealing with thousands of ip's and subnets, and it needs to match with the CLOSEST ip. I am thinking it may not be picking up all the cells in the spreadsheet? Because the IP address that gets inputted is a string variable, and when I use a code I commented out to display all columns it gets all the columns.!

```
System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Investigations
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;
            string str;


            IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8");
            IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
            Console.WriteLine("IP Address: " + addr);
            Console.WriteLine("Host Name: " + entry.HostName);


            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\subnets.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            Excel.Range currentFind = null;
            Excel.Range firstFind = null;
            Excel.XlFindLookIn xlValues;
            Excel.XlLookAt xlPart;

            string columnSubnet = "Network"; // change to the correct header

            Match match = Regex.Match(columnSubnet, @".*[0-3148].*");
            for (int i = 0; i < xlWorksheet.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                // get the current row
                DataRow row = xlWorksheet.Rows[i];
                // get the ID from the row
                string idValue = row[columnSubnet].ToString();
                // check if the row value is equal to the textbox entry
                bool myMatch = idValue.Equals(addr);
                // if both of the above are true, do this
                if (match.Success && myMatch == true)
                {
                    Console.Write(idValue);
                    Console.WriteLine(" -This id was found");
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple issues in your code in regards to object types.

First off the variable `addr` is of type `IPAddress` but later you are trying to compare the value to a string. A string object will never equal an `IPAddress` object. You need to parse the incoming ip `string` into an `IPAddress` object itself also like so:

```
IPAddress idValue = IPAddress.Parse(row[columnSubnet].ToString());
```

Secondly, in regards to your stated issue, `xlWorksheet.Rows[i]` gives you a `Range` object, not a `DataRow` object. Your code does not show that datarow being saved anywhere so I assume you are just using it to get your value. You can pull the needed value directly this way without having to check the regex either: (This assumes you know the column index)

```
for (int i = 0; i < xlWorksheet.Rows.Count; i++)
{   
    IPAddress excelIP;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse(xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, <ip column index>].Value.ToString(), out excelIP)) 
    {
        Console.Write(excelIP.toString());
        Console.WriteLine(" -This id was found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense then. I  just thought because addr stored a value I could just use it like that. Thank you very much

Comment: Index meaning like if it were in column B then you would use `.Cells[i + 1, 2]`. Both row and columns indexes start at 1 and increment up.

Comment: IPAddress idValue = IPAddress.Parse(row[columnSubnet].ToString());

I am getting an error on the row. It could be where I have it placed?

This line here [i + 1, <ip column index>]. I have errors too

along with Console.Write(excelIP.toString()); line.

Am I missing any parameters?

Comment: Use the method above with `xlWorksheet.Cells[r,c].Value.ToString()` instead of `row[columnSubnet].ToString()`

Comment: the r,c have red under them. I have a couple other issues as well, I posted in the comment above. I get the logic, I have never imported an excel sheet before so I am a little new to this.

Comment: You need to replace r and c with the correct row and column index integers. Since you are looping over rows you'll use i + 1 for the row index.

Comment: IPAddress idValue = IPAddress.Parse(row[columnSubnet].ToString()); 

Just getting an error under row. Either than that everything seems fine

Comment: See above. Don't use `row[columnSubnet]` at all. Use the `.Cells` reference instead. If you need to dynamically find the column index then that is a whole different answer altogether.

Comment: IPAddress idValue = IPAddress.Parse( i + 1[columnSubnet].ToString()); ?

Comment: IPAddress idValue = IPAddress.Parse(A1 :A3000.Cells()); ?

Comment: Do you or do you not know the column index from the excel sheet which contains the IP information? If so then use the code I posted above in the answer or adapt as needed. Otherwise I can post a means of dynamically finding the column index (which is an entirely different approach) later as needed.

Comment: I know the columns that contain it, it's from A2 - A3100.

Comment: Ok so that means it's column A which is column index 1. Use the code I posted in the original answer and replace `<ip column index>` with `1`

Comment: if (IPAddress.TryParse(xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1].Value.ToString(), out excelIP)) 

It's crashing at this line with a handling exception, I deleted all my old loop code and just kept yours

Comment: That's because you didn't include the column index like I mentioned. Cells[] requires two arguments both the row and column index.

Comment: if (IPAddress.TryParse(xlWorksheet.Cells[i + 1, 2].Value.ToString(), out excelIP)) ?

Comment: Why would you use the number 2 when we just established that it's column index 1?

Comment: i + 1 gives you the row index since we are looping over the rows with i. The second argument needs to be the number 1 since the desired column is index 1 aka column A

Comment: I Have it as just [i  +1], I am sorry I am just a little confused there.

Comment: `.Cells[i + 1, 1]`

Comment: Yes it has worked, thank you so much, I have to figure out how to incorporate another cell with that, but now I got the general idea I think?

Comment: Awesome, yep just adapt from there. I highly suggest reading some c# tutorials and some of the excel object documentation in c#.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't programmed in quite a while, I just started working on a project to make my life a little easier haha.

Comment: No problem! If this worked for you then please accept the main answer by clicking the checkmark below the up and down vote buttons.

Comment: I realized a small issue, every column in that cell ends in a /1-24 network. Is there a way for it to still print the closest ip?